# Dynamic images resizing

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, python

I'm working on project where we are trying to adopt and resize template images to the various resolutions. For example if the website is viewed in 800px width (800x600) and 1024px width or larger the image size should be viewed in same quality. 
I've had in mind to use sprite with 3 types of images for each range of this template , but I'm looking for other ideas , php gd maybe ? Any python solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) will give you dynamic resizing, processing, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Well, for resizing it would of course be better to use GD... But indexed, I think. So that you have an upload script that automatically generates the images' in other sizes, and saves them somewhere.

However, it matters whether you have more disk space, or performance... Performance would get worse IF you have many people viewing these images. Disk space would get worse IF you have A LOT of these images.

Answer (score 2):

If you are resizing to a known set of resolutions, you can just resize your images once and store them.

If you need to resize for any possible resolution, you will need a library to do that for you.  In PHP, [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [ImageMagik](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) are both good.

If you do this, you may want to add caching for the most common resolutions.  This will take up more disc space, but will save you the cost of recalculating all the images every time.

Note that it can be difficult to detect the true resolution though.  If the browser window is resized, the resolution you think the screen is may not be the actual resolution the user can see.  The same can happen if they have toolbars or sidebars opened.

Answer (score 1):

Why not resize the image on the client using JavaScript?

```
<head>
<script>
function resize() {
    ww = window.innerWidth
    wh = window.innerHeight
    photo = document.getElementById("photo")
    // You probably wouldn't actually make the image fill the window, you'd pick
    // some appropriate size.
    photo.setAttribute("width", ww)
    photo.setAttribute("height", wh)
}
</head>
<body onload="resize()" onresize="resize()">
<img id="photo" src="photo.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting the inner window width is quite hard, as different browsers use different variables. However, this is what I use on my website. It gets the inner window width rather reliably, and then sets the image width/height. It shouldn't be too hard to modify this code to set the src of the image desired.

```
function set_image_sizes(){
    if (window.innerHeight != undefined) {
        height = window.innerHeight;
        width = window.innerWidth;
    } else if (document.documentElement.clientHeight > 0) {
        height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    } else {
        height = document.body.clientHeight;
        width = document.body.clientWidth;
    }

    $('#image').css('height', height);
    $('#image').css('width', width);

}
```